# SQL statement change db_owner value for a specific user

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to change db_owner field to true for the user BUILTIN\Users.

what is the SQL i need to do in sql server 2008 ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'BUILTIN\Users'
```

In general the format for a windows login should be:

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', '<computer>\<user>'
```

[MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187750.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. I added also USE <database name>

Comment: Yep, I assumed you were running it on the correct database to begin with ;-)